# Woocommerce My Account - Add titles to "Edit Address" sections

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm designing My Account sections and noticed that the address sections don't have any titles
[image: My website]

So my problems are:

1. How can I add titles to the sections? My goal is to look like this (image found online)
   [image: Goal]
2. How do I change the arrangements just only for My Account page? Cus I want to move the phone number below customer's name.

Any information would really help. At the moment I don't know what to search for, any time I try "add titles for the address woocommerce", they all aim to the checkout page, which is currently fine for me.

Comment: To change address page layout on woocommerce myaccount page, the woocommerce plugin file "templates/woocommerce/myaccount/my-address.php" can be checked.

Comment: @Jai Inside the file is php code pulling address details and echo them out, I cannot find and edit them individually though.

Comment: The HTML code will need to be put, using address details, according to required layout. Please note this point: "This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/my-address.php.".